# How to check if atleast one item in 1 out of 4 listboxes is selected

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to write a JS validation function for multi-select listboxes.

I have 4 multi-select listboxes and I need to check if the user has selected from atleast one listbox value.  That is, out of 4 listbox, user should select from atleast 1 listbox (any number of values).

This is the function I am writing,

```
function validate(form)
{
    if ((document.getElementById("A").value=='') || (document.getElementById("B").value=='') || (document.getElementById("C").value=='') || (document.getElementById("D").value=='')) 
    {                                           
        if (0 < message.length) { message += "\n"; }
        message += "You must select atleast one of the listbox items ";

    }
}
```

I know the problem is with the OR condition. It does not allow to save the form unless 1 value from **each** of these listbox is selected.

But I need to check for **minimum 1 out of 4 listbox** (any number of items) should be selected.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours needs to be changed to use the AND condition and it will be the appropriate Sad Path approach:

```
if (document.getElementById("A").value == '' && 
    document.getElementById("B").value == '' && 
    document.getElementById("C").value == '' && 
    document.getElementById("D").value == '') {

    //then they didn't select AT LEAST ONE item
 }
 else {       
    //they did pick at least one
 }
```

Edit:

You can go with a Happy Path approach by doing the following:

```
 if (document.getElementById("A").value !='' || 
     document.getElementById("B").value !='' || 
     document.getElementById("C").value !='' || 
     document.getElementById("D").value !='') {

     //then they did select AT LEAST ONE item
  }
  else {       
     //they didn't pick at least one
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a much simpler way to do it :

```
element = document.getElementById("myid");
selected_index = element.selectedIndex;
```

if there is no selected element in my listbox, then **selected_index** will return **-1**
that is because we know that item indexes in a list box goes **from 0 to (n)**, so if nothing selected it makes sense that they put it to **-1**
the rest is up to you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&&` operator, which mean, if all four together are not selected then you want to show the message.

With `||` condition, it works differently i.e. it will set the message to display **if any of the boxes are not selected.**

Remember, for `||`, `false|| true|| false|| false ->> true`
and for `&&`, `false && true && false && false ->> false`

In your case, say for example, one select box is selected, then  since `false|| true|| false|| false ->> true`, it will still enter inside the `if` which you don't want. Instead, you would like to enter inside if when all select boxes are not selected i.e. `true && true && true && true --> true`.

Answer (score 0):

In continuation with validation... I have a text field which is set as unique in the database.
I have written a Java function to check the field is unique by comparing with the database values.

Now my validation works fine in the servlet and the user is propmpted with a new screen.

Is there a way I can use the java function to pop up an alert just like how we do UI validation in case of java scripts?

I believe JS is only for UI validation but want to check if there is a way to validate by comparing against the database values?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the value of a select element might be "" in IE if the selected option doesn't have a value attribute. Better to check the select element's *selectedIndex* property.

Also, if no option has the selected attribute, some browsers might select the first option by default and others might not, so the *selectedIndex* might be 0 or -1 with no user input. A a robust strategy is to always set one option (usually the first) as the default selected option.

If the default is always the first option, and all your select elements have an ID attribute, you can do:

```
function checkSelects(ids) {
  var i = ids.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (document.getElementById(ids[i]).selectedIndex) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note that if the select elements have a name (which they must have to be successful in a form), you can also do:

```
function checkSelects(form, names) {
  var i = names.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (form[names[i].selectedIndex) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```